# Como instalar um pacote manualmente em um projeto React Native?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, npm

Preciso instalar um pacote no meu projeto React Native, mas ao utilizar o comando npm para instalação:

```
npm install react-native-threatmetrix --save
```

Recebo o seguinte erro como resposta:

```
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for react-native-threatmetrix
```

Logo, parece não haver mais uma versão do pacote disponível. Mas tenho acesso ao projeto no GitHub (https://github.com/teopeurt/react-native-threatmetrix), e queria saber, se possível, como faço para instalá-lo manualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode instalar a partir do GitHub assim:

```sh
npm install git+https://git@github.com/teopeurt/react-native-threatmetrix.git
```